# OPtimizing the SQL Query

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization

I want to optimize the following query

```
Select Distinct(Column_A) from Table_name where Column_B = 'Something'
```

THis basically does a full table scan (around 7.5 million records). I would like to know if I can add an index on this column_A so that it would do a FULL index scan, Or is there any other better solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an index on `Table_name(Column_B, Column_A)`.  The index "covers" the query, so only the index should be accessed for the query.

EDIT:

I keep thinking about this.  Even with the index, some SQL engines are likely to sort the data for resolving the `distinct`.  The following query might possibly be faster:

```
select column_A
from table_name t
where column_B = 'Something' and
      t.id = (select min(id)
              from table_name t2
              where t2.column_A = t.column_A and t2.column_B = t.column_B
             );
```

For this to work, it would need an index on `table_name(column_A, column_B, id)`.  This assumes a unique `id` on each row in addition to the index.

Comment: But is there any other way , other than creating indexes?

Comment: You could partition by table by `Column_B`.

Comment: Or materialized view.

Comment: One more concern, the issue is Column_A has around 7.3 million NULL values, So adding index can't do much help here i suppose.

Comment: @user1270123 . . . If most of the values are `NULL`, you can help the SQL engine optimize the query by doing `where column_B = 'Something' and column_A is not null`, along with the index on `column_B, column_A` (in that order).